# Packaging Python applications with configuration files

Tags: python, configuration-files, packaging

I'm using ConfigParser for configuring my application, and now I want to make it easily distributable, and at the same time preserve the configurability.

I'm thinking I need a directory with configuration file templates, and some way of generating the configuration to actually use from these. Then I need a place to store it that will work in virtualenv, the users home directory etc. I want it to be as close to how normal Unix packages work, i.e. have config in etc, but with overrides in home directory. Is there a readymade solution for this, and if not, what should I put in my setup.py etc to make it work like I want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use [`data_files`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) option of `distutils` to install files wherever you want.

`data_files` specifies a sequence of `(directory, files)` pairs in the following way:

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[('/etc', ['cfg/config1.ini', 'cfg/config2.ini']),
                  ('/etc/init.d', ['bin/initscript1'])],
      ....
     )
```

When reading the config file on your app, you can merge a `/home` version if it exists, using [`.read()` method of `ConfigParser` objects](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read):

```
files_read = cfgparserobj.read(['/etc/config1.ini', 
                                os.path.expanduser('~/.config1.ini')])
for fname in files_read:
    print "Reading config from", fname
```

That will read `/etc/config1.ini` and then overwrite the definitions with stuff coming from `.config1.ini` in the user's home directory, if it exists.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work nice with virtualenv? I.e. what path should I specify to put stuff in myvirtenv/etc/myconf.ini ?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but still can be usefull. @JoakimLundborg: you can use ``sys.prefix``, which is by default ``/usr``, and the path of your virtualenv in your case (with the real prefix in ``sys.real_prefix``

Comment: Using sys.real_prefix seems very promising, it would require also a way to get the same location at runtime to read the configuration file from there; can the same be used for that purpose?